# "thus allowing..." vs "thus allow..."

Tags: sentence-construction

This sentence is from [OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/thus?q=thus), under its entry for *thus*:

> The universities have expanded, thus allowing many more people the chance of higher education.

Is "thus allowing" a short form for "thus they are allowing"?

Would it be correct to replace "thus allowing" with "thus allow" here?

> The universities have expanded, **thus allow** many more people the chance of higher education.

Answer (score 0):

The substitution works if you insert more words -- "The universities have expanded and thus now allow many more people the chance of higher education." The first example, "thus allowing", expresses a continuous sense. The second example expresses the present tense.

However, the original sentence is clearer and more concise. It's clearly connecting cause and effect.

Comment: No, the original sentence from Oxford Learner's Dictionaries doesn't indicate "a continuous sense". It is a present participial phrase functioning as an adverbial and modifying the main clause.